# Bloomberg drawing out multiple securities

Tags: bloomberg

The Bloomberg excel formumla `=BDH()` only retrieves the prices for 1 security. If I want to get other securities, I'll need to repeat the formula which is no issue as I've written a script for that.

The problem comes when the dates of the securities doesn't match up, either due to trading days or contract expiry.

E.g. `=BDH(name_of_commod,"PX_LAST","19/12/2015","2/5/2017")` for two separate tickers produces:

```
QWV8 Comdty         QWZ8 Comdty 
#NAME?      495.2   #NAME?      479.7
14/2/2017   496.7   18/4/2017   462.2
15/2/2017   494.4   19/4/2017   457.1
16/2/2017   495.3   20/4/2017   456.6
17/2/2017   495     21/4/2017   457
20/2/2017   498.7   24/4/2017   454.9
21/2/2017   498.4   25/4/2017   453.5
22/2/2017   498.1   26/4/2017   445
23/2/2017   491.6   27/4/2017   439.9
24/2/2017   489.5   28/4/2017   450
27/2/2017   481.6   2/5/2017    448.4
```

The mismatch here is due to that `QWZ8` is not available till 18th Apr, which kind of screws over my calculations as I've got about a hundred other securities in the data set.

Is there a way to output bloomberg data such that all the dates align to the same row?

Like such:

```
    QWV8 Comdty         QWZ8 Comdty 
18/4/2017   461.3   18/4/2017   462.2
19/4/2017   456.2   19/4/2017   457.1
20/4/2017   455.7   20/4/2017   456.6
21/4/2017   456.1   21/4/2017   457
24/4/2017   454     24/4/2017   454.9
25/4/2017   452.6   25/4/2017   453.5
26/4/2017   444     26/4/2017   445
27/4/2017   438.9   27/4/2017   439.9
28/4/2017   449     28/4/2017   450
2/5/2017    447.4   2/5/2017    448.4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use overrides to specify how missing dates are handled. For example:

```
=BDH(name_of_commod,"PX_LAST","19/12/2015","2/5/2017","Days=W,Fill=N")
```

will have one datapoint for each workday and if no data was available for a date will leave the "price" cell blank.

The possible values are for `Days` are:

- N, W or Weekdays - All weekdays
- C, A or All - All calendar days
- T, Trading- Omits all non-trading days.

and for `Fill`:

- C, P, or Previous - Carries over the last available data.
- N, E, or Error - Returns an error message.
- B or Blank - Returns a blank.
- NA - Excel is not available
- PNA - Previous value and Excel is #N/A when the previous value is not available
- Any other value the client enters will be used literally as a filler.

You can find a more exhaustive list of valid overrides in the help for the function. (In Excel, go to the cell with the formula and click "More Functions..." and "Help on this function")